# Speaker Identification / Recognition for less size audio files

Tags: generative-model, data-science, speech-recognition, state-of-the-art

I am working on speaker identification problem using GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model). I have to just identify one user present in the given audio, so for second class noise or silent audio may use or not just like in image classification for an object we create a non-object class.

I have used a silent class is always showing the user is present ( which is not).

If any other model can give better accuracy fulfil the condition that only 30 sec of audio of a particular user is available and given test audio may has long size.

Comment: Why did you choose GMMs? Any intuitions ? Why not Neural Nets?

Comment: The speaker files will be maximum 30seconds and 3-5 files only (for training). Since GMM is a statistical model as a statistical model works better with small data compare to the neural network.